# Reverse proxy to subdirectory using Nginx causes the path problem

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am now trying to reverse proxy my SolidJS app through Nginx.

My app is running on the 3000 port. (http://example.com:3000)

However, I want to reverse proxy this app to subdirectory (https://example.com/myapp)

The nginx works correctly while using the root directory (https://example.com/) but it does not load the page correctly with subdirectory.

I tried several solutions in the internet, but none of those helped me. Following codes are one of the things I tried.

```
location /myapp/ {
  rewrite ^/myapp/(.*)$ /$1 break;
  proxy_pass http://example.com:3000/;
}
```

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  location /myapp {
    proxy_pass http://example.com:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    # Set the base URL of the React app
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host example.com;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Path /myapp;
  }
}
```

If there is another solution, I would try it.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the nginx reverse proxy - sends the /myapp path attached with the incoming rqeuest - and your application does not understand the /myapp prefix. My advice try adding /myapp default prefix for all your routes in the application.

Comment: So, is there no way without changing routes in application? Our plan is using this app to deploy multiple servers with multiple subdirectories, so that would be quite tricky.